# UIViewController doesn't dealloc because of an animation loop

Tags: ios, core-animation, nsoperation

I have a method that performs a simple animation then calls itself again. The problem is that the `UIViewController` is never `dealloc`'d, I assume because of the continuous run loop.

If I comment out the line that recalls the animation method, it gets `dealloc`'d fine.

I have tried using `performSelector` to loop the animation, but calling `[NSOperation cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];` in `viewWillDisappear` doesn't seem to cancel it. Possibly because i'm using `afterDelay:0.0`?

Here is my animation method:

```
- (void)animateArrows
{
    UIImage *toImage;
    switch (animState) {
        case ARROWS:
            toImage = arrow_1;
            animState++;
            break;

        case ARROW_1:
            toImage = arrows;
            animState++;
            break;

        case ARROWS_1:
            toImage = arrow_2;
            animState++;
            break;

        case ARROW_2:
            toImage = arrows;
            animState++;
            break;

        case ARROWS_2:
            toImage = arrow_3;
            animState++;
            break;

        case ARROW_3:
            toImage = arrows;
            animState = ARROWS;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.sendButton
                      duration:0.6f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                    animations:^{
                        [self.sendButton setImage:toImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

                        [self performSelector:@selector(animateArrows) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
//                        [self animateArrows];
                    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add a `BOOL` property that indicates whether or not the animation should keep looping. Then change that animation block to something like:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.sendButton
                  duration:0.6f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                animations:^{
                    [self.sendButton setImage:toImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    if (self.repeatAnimations)
                    {
                        [self performSelector:@selector(animateArrows) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
                    }
                }];
```

The reason you need to perform this check is that you have an otherwise infinite loop that is retaining `self`. Once you leave this loop your view controller will be `dealloc`'d.

Comment: Spot on, so simple. Thanks